# Hangfire FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly DynamicProxyGenAssembly,

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I am having an issue with HangFire after i set a background job it get set but when i open the HangFire dashboard i see the following **exception**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

All interfaces are being registered using AutoFac for DI. , I am setting up the following in the startup.cs

I have the following code in the startup

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("Hangfire");
  app.UseHangfireDashboard();
  app.UseHangfireServer();
```

I have the following ocde to schule the job

```
 public class ScheduleAppService : IScheduleAppService
  {
    private readonly IRunCommandAppService _runCommandAppService;

    public ScheduleAppService(IRepository<Schedule> repository, IAdHocTemplateRunnerAppService adHocTemplateRunner) : base(repository)
    {
      _adHocTemplateRunner = adHocTemplateRunner;
    }

    public async Task CreateSchedule(ScheduleDto schedule)
    {
      input.Schedule.JobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(
        () => _runCommandAppService.AddTemplate(
          new Template{ RunId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), TemplateId = schedule.Id }), schedule.Start);
    }
}
```

The code which is being called is here

```
 public class RunCommandAppService  : IRunCommandAppService 
  {
    private readonly IRepository<Template> _templateRepo;

    public RunCommandAppService (IRepository<Template> templateRepo)
    {
      _templateRepo = templateRepo;
    }

    public void AddTemplate(Template input)
    {
      try
      {
        Run(input);
      }
      finally
      {
        SetRunComplate(input.RunId);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I've followed all the dependencies for Hangfire: http://www.nuget.org/packages/HangFire/ but couldn't find a reference to this.  Are you sure it isn't a dependency from one of your services or repositories? Are you binding all your dependencies before starting hangfire?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, When you say binding you mean setting them up with autofac? How do you set them up for hangfire?

Comment: Do you create your ContainerBuilder before or after starting Hangfire?

Comment: before, and the same method works fine when not called with hangfire,I check to see if the container had everything before the hangfire config is called and its all there.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the same context as yours but I think it's still worth adding it here:
-Hangfire server was running as a Windows service;
-Hangfire dashboard running on top of a ASP.NET MVC 5 app;
-jobs were actually running but dashboard kept displaying a FileNotFoundException;

**Solution:**  added a reference to the missing assembly (ie: 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2') in the dashboard web app.

Same problem was reported and solved in the same way by [@reggieboyYEAH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219144/hangfire-failes-to-load-assembly#comment61097083_35219144).
Details here: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/558

Answer (score 0):

I also have same issue. But I try to move the method which contains `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` to a vm class. When I want to call this method I will new a vm class. Then use vm to call the method. It will be a success. I think the reason is some resource is used by two object at the same time.  Anyway it can run. I hope this can help you.

My exception is like below:

```
warn: Hangfire.AutomaticRetryAttribute[0]
  Failed to process the job '15': an exception occurred. Retry attempt 3 of 10 will be performed in 00:01:01.
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 未能加载文件或程序集“DynamicProxyGenAssembly2,     Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null”或它的某一个依赖项。系统找不到指定的文件。
文件名:“DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null”
   在 System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   在 System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   在 System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   在 Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.Deserialize()

=== 预绑定状态信息 ===
日志: DisplayName = DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
日志: Appbase = file:///D:/Code/Test/bin/Debug/net461/
日志: 初始 PrivatePath = NULL
调用程序集: Hangfire.Core, Version=1.6.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null。`
===
日志: 此绑定从 default 加载上下文开始。
日志: 正在使用应用程序配置文件: D:\Code\Test\bin\Debug\net461\ Test.exe.Config
日志: 使用主机配置文件:
日志: 使用 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config 的计算机配置文件。
日志: 此时没有为引用应用策略(私有、自定义、分部或基于位置的程序集绑定)。
日志: 相同的绑定已出现过，因 hr = 0x80070002 而失败。
```

Answer (score -1):

```
input.Schedule.JobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule<IAdHocTemplateRunnerAppService >(
            x =>
                x.AddTemplate (new Template{ RunId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), TemplateId = schedule.Id }), input.Schedule.Start);
```

Comment: Please also add some details that how your provide code is going to solve OP problem.