# Hangfire dynamically loading assemblies via. Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, system.reflection, hangfire

I'm currently having trouble integrating Hangfire into our solutions.
We have currently a system consisting of three components.

- Modular MVC Application
- Windows Service as a BackgroundJob Server (Hangfire)
- MVC Application with Hangfire Dashboard

The Windows Service is now loading the assemblies from the modular Application (due to release cycles).

This is done via. [Assembly.LoadFrom()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1009fa28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

When we now Schedule a job via. the MVC Application, the job fails with the error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.Module.Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have already had a look at the following posts, but they do not mach what I need:

- [Hangfire failes to load assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219144/hangfire-failes-to-load-assembly)
- https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/558
- [Hangfire FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly DynamicProxyGenAssembly,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991196/hangfire-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-dynamicproxygena?rq=1)
- and others

Other infos:

1. I can not reference the shared assemblies directly, it must be loaded at runtime
2. I can not use a common interface project, that has to be referenced
3. I can't customise hangfire like this [Hangfire branche](https://github.com/gandarez/Hangfire)

Has anyone an idea, how to implement this without adding references

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Michael

Comment: Can you use one of the IOC Hangfire libraries? Seems like you could wire the class construction up yourself to pull from the shared assembly when setting up the IOC container and then Hangfire would construct using that.

Comment: Are you sure it is the job failing, not just the Dashboard failing to show the results? You need to load job assemblies into Dashboard application too for them to be correctly displayed there.

Comment: Did you ever get a clear answer on this or figure it out?

Comment: @Michael Lopez: Did you able to figure out. We have the exact same need.